# Simulate a click through JavaScript on a rich text format web button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to automate a task through a Chrome extension interacting with the DOM of a web page.
The issue I'm running into is basically triggering a click on the button of a rich text format toolbar, similar to the one you can find on the compose window of Gmail or on Stack Overflow.

To take the example of the "Insert link" button of Gmail (id: ":1wd") for example, I tried unsuccessfully:

1. Triggering a click through `click()`

   ```
   document.getElementById(":1wd").click()
   ```

The issue here seems to be that there are no event listeners attached to the button directly.

2. getting the coordinates X and Y of the button and triggering a mouse event:

   ```
   var evt = new MouseEvent("click", { 
     clientX : buttonX, // where buttonX is the X coordinate
     clientY : buttonY  // where buttonY is the Y coordinate
   });

   document.dispatchEvent(evt);
   ```
3. putting the focus on the input window and triggering a keyboard event for the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>):

   ```
   var evt = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
     "ctrlKey": true,
     "key": "k"
   });
   document.dispatchEvent(evt);
   ```

Do you have any idea how this could be done?

Edit: On the HTML: I checked the HTML and events in the page, it seems that the event listener is of type `mousedown` and attached to the overarching div, at the toolbar level. My guess is that clicks on the button trigger this toolbar-level event and a function that takes as input the exact button that was clicked. Unfortunately the JS code is minified so I can't really debug.

Comment: So how are the event listeners attached to the button?  They must be, somehow.  Figure that out, then you can simulate the click.

Comment: use `elm.dispatchEvent`, not document.dispatchEvent...

Comment: In what context are you trying to run the above code? Can you add your manifest and/or how you inject this code? Also, _please_ get rid of snippet tags.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I removed the snippet tags and put some HTML context. Dandavis: thanks, I'll try it tomorrow.